# How to deploy Asp.net core web api with locally installed MongoDB to Microsoft Azure?

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, asp.net-core

I am new to ASP.Net Core and MongoDB, I am trying to create simple API and host my API globally so that other's also could use. At this stage, I have created the ASP.Net Core Web Api using MongoDB locally, and when I try to publish on Microsoft Azure with student account that's given from my university, there is something wrong. I have no idea what steps should i complete to achieve working API. On Azure side, I have created the CosmosDB with MongoDB Api but i am not able to migrate my local database on it, and I have published my API from Visual Studio, the link on App Service on Azure is not found. Please, can you suggest step by step solutions of how to complete this?
I have searched the net, and found out that i should make migration service on Azure but when it comes to setup the source by making action on migration project, I do not know what is my source server name.

Here are some screen shots of what i have now.

[image: THIS IS ON AZURE MAIN DASHBOARD]

[image: THIS IS MY MIGRATION SERVICE]

Comment: Unless your local MongoDB instance is exposed on the internet, Azure isn't going to be able to pull from it. There are tools like NGROK that can expose local applications to the internet that might work. But it may be simpler to just use mongodump to export the local database and then load that into Azure using mongo.

Comment: Yeah knowing that, I wasnot able to do what i wanted. How about using MongoDB Atlas, and Azure pulls the data from Atlas? Is that possible?

Comment: You could probably pull from Atlas but how does that help? You have the data locally, right and you want it in Cosmos.

Comment: Yeah, it does not help. Then what can I do? I am struggling on this issue